# How to extract certain Character from JS String

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Given a String that represents a math operation , i want to extract the operations it contains , for ex : `5+4-3` will return two `arrays` : Operations = `[+,-]` and the operands will be `[5,4,3]`

```js
// grab the input and so stuff when user finishes typing

const selectElement = document.querySelector('.formule');
selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');
  segmentFormule(event.target.value);
});


const segmentFormule = function (value){
// first separate operands from operations
    let myOperands = [];
    const formule = new String(value);
    
    // here i extracted the operands into an array, but i couldnt figure out how to extract the operations , so i just hardcoded Addition operation for now.
    
    myOperands=formule.split("+");
    
    let ColoredFormule = "";
    for (var i = 0 ; i < myOperands.length ; i++ ) {
        ColoredFormule += 
        '<span style="color:Red">'+myOperands[i]+'</span> '+'<span style="color:blue">+</span> ';
    }
    document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = ColoredFormule;
    
    }
```

```html
<label for="formuleField">Example input: 56+400+300</label>
</br>
<input type="text" class="formule" name="formuleField">
</br>
<div class="result"></div>
```

I Couldnt figure out how to extract the operations from the given input, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to create two arrays using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). The first match will match against all none numbers, the second will match against all the numbers.

If you want integers in your operators array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) over the array passing in [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) for the callback.

```js
const str = '5.14 + 4 - 36';
const operations = str.match(/[^\d \.]/g);
const operands = str.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g).map(Number);
console.log(operations, operands)
```

Comment: You might want `/\d+/g` for second match

Comment: Thanks. Good spot @Keith

Comment: But Andy , if i use " 5.34 + 500 " , the "." will count as a operation and i will have one extra digit as follows :  [ 5, 34 , 500 ]

Comment: You should have included that information in your question, but I'll take a look.

Comment: @Abdou answer updated.

Comment: Do floats always start with a number before the point or might it just be '.3'? (In this case the regex wouldn't work)

Comment: @Corrl I answer the question that's been asked. If there are edge-cases that the OP hasn't provided in the question I'm not going to second-guess them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with string.match()
(notice the digits are strings, if you need numbers, you have to convert)

```js
let value = '56.2+400-300/200*.23'

const operatorsRegex = /[+\-/*]/g

let operators = value.match(operatorsRegex)

console.log(operators) // ['+','-','/','*']

const digitsRegex = /(\d+\.?\d*)|(\.?\d+)/g

let digits = value.match(digitsRegex)
console.log(digits) // ["56.2", "400", "300", "200", ".23"]
```

Comment: any idea how to get around floats  ? using 3.14 for example will count the "." as an operation , and my digits will be [3, 14 , ...rest ]

Comment: @Abdou I just made a correction so the floats are found